# EF copies existing entity instead of linking

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I believe there are some errors in my EF codefirst settings or something.
So I have two entites:

```
public class Product
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public virtual ProductList ProductList { get; set; }

}
```

and

```
public class ProductList
{
    public ProductList()
    {
        this.Products = new List<Product>();
    }

    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Title { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Product> Products { get; set; }
}
```

and context

```
public class ApplicationDbContext :
{
    public DbSet<ProductList> ProductLists { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Product> Products { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<ProductList>().HasMany(p => p.Products).WithRequired(p => p.ProductList).WillCascadeOnDelete(true);
    }
}
```

I assume that I have product list in my DB.
And when I am creating product I want to do something like this:

```
var productListId = 1;
var product = new Product
    {
        Name = "New product",
        ProductList = db.ProductLists.Find(productListId)
    };

db.Products.Add(product);
db.SaveChanges();
```

I am expecting that in table Products will be inserted new line

```
Id  Name            ProductList_Id
1   New Product     1
```

But instead EF creates new ProductList with the same values like the one that I am trying to link, saves it and links my Product to this new ProductList.

Answer (score 0):

To get the behavior you want, your Product entity should contain `ProductListID` as a one-to-many foreign key linked to the ProductList entity.